# Gridview related problem in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How can I enter data from textbox to gridview on the buttonclick event

Comment: I'd prefer how would I make an airplane fly without engines to this one.

Comment: I may be wrong, but just displaying text in a Grid could not be a task; **what you want in actual to accomplish?**

Comment: @Pabuc: 1) Find a mountain. 2) Carry the airplane to the top. 3) Push it off the side.

@Atul: Are you wanting to add an item (row) from a textbox & gridview *outside* of the grid or from within it (in the footer)? Please provide a more detailed description of your scenario, since we don't really have enought info to go on.

Answer (score 0):

A gridview is more commonly used for databinding to a source of table-like data. If you're just moving text from textboxes to grid/table, you might be better off using a regular table with empty asp labels in the cells. On postback, you can:

```
lblCell11.Text = txtBox1.Text;
```